# twitter4j OAuth Android

Tags: android, oauth, twitter4j

what is the conventional way of dealing with this new type of authentication twitter has implemented. I don't think I am doing it  it correctly, right now I have this activity:

[image]

So the user in order to authenticate the app they have to get a pin which they have to get by clicking on get Pin button.

which has this code:

```
@
Override
protected String doInBackground(Void...params) {

    String s = null;

    twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer("XXXX", "XXXXX");




    try {
        requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();

        s = requestToken.getAuthorizationURL();

    } catch (TwitterException e) {



        e.printStackTrace();
    }




    return s;
}

@
Override
protected void onPostExecute(String url) {


    Intent intent = new Intent(AuthenticateActivity.this, Oauth_web_view.class);
    intent.putExtra("url", url);
    startActivity(intent);




}
}
```

that takes them to another activity which is just a webview and lets them get their pin, after that they input their pin, they have to submit pin which they press the submit pin button there's this code.

```
 class AddUserCreds extends AsyncTask < Void, String, String > {

     @
     Override
     protected String doInBackground(Void...urls) {


         //String url = urls[0];




         String pin = txtPin.getText().toString();
         System.out.println(pin);

         //  try{
         //  if(pin.length() > 0){
         try {
             accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, pin);

             // Shared Preferences
             Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();

             // After getting access token, access token secret
             // store them in application preferences
             e.putString("PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN", accessToken.toString());
             //   Store login status - true
             e.putBoolean("PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN", true);
             e.commit(); // save changes

             Log.e("Twitter OAuth Token", "> " + accessToken.getToken());
         } catch (TwitterException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
         }




         // }
         //   } catch (TwitterException te) {
         //   if(401 == te.getStatusCode()){
         // //    System.out.println("Unable to get the access token.");
         //  }else{
         //     te.printStackTrace();
         //   }
         //  }
         return "done";


         // 




     }


     @
     Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String url) {




         AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AuthenticateActivity.this);

         alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("You've been authenticated" + url);

         alertDialogBuilder.show();




     }
```

it worked once and it added my twitter dev account to a fake account I made but now if I run it again it breaks because it's already authenticated. Is there a way to test if I am authenticated already ? so they do not have to go through this process ? Is there a more streamlined process of getting authentication ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do is to first read the auth toekn/secret from the preferences (which I saved during the first authentication, as you already do), and if I see it was saved, I use it instead of performing an additional auth attempt. See below a snippet of my code, hope it helps:

```
        String authToken = prefs.getString(PREF_TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN, null);
        String authTokenSecret = prefs.getString(PREF_TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, null);
        if (authToekn == null)
        {
             //... perform auth
        }
        else //we're ready to go
        { 
          ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
          cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
            .setOAuthConsumerKey(APIKEY)
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret(APISECRET)
            .setOAuthAccessToken(authToken)
            .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(authTokenSecret);
          twitterConnection = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
        }
```